# How to put results from a SQL query into its own object on LEFT JOIN in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

I have the following query in my NodeJS project:

```
    db.query(
      'SELECT posts.* , users.username from posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.u_id = users.id',
      (err,results) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).json(err);
        else {
          return res.status(200).json(results);
        }
      }
    )
```

with following results:

```
[
   {id:3, description: "First post", img: "../assets/test.png", username:"testUser"}
]
```

How would I put data corresponding to a user in its own object like that:

```
[
  {id:3, description: "Fist post", img: "../assets/test.png", user: {username: "testUser"}}
]
```

If I would have more than one LEFT JOIN it would be difficult to manually put all the data into its corresponding object.

Comment: While I'm not very familiar with mySQL have a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object).

Comment: @camwhite Hey, I will. Thank you.

Comment: I would handle any further data manipulation in your application code